# Aerospike query execution in golang

Tags: go, aerospike

Is there any way to implement below query in golang :

select * from test.demo in mapvalues where shopping_cart = "FL"

Answer (score 3):

Check out the examples in the [sandbox](https://developer.aerospike.com/): https://developer.aerospike.com/client/usage/queries/basic/secondary

Here is the sample code for a range query on the canonical ufodata set in the sandbox (you would first have to create the secondary index of course):

```
// Create new query policy
queryPolicy := aerospike.NewQueryPolicy()
queryPolicy.FilterExpression = aerospike.ExpGeoCompare(
    aerospike.ExpGeoBin("location"), 
    aerospike.ExpGeoVal(region))

// Create statement
stmt := aerospike.NewStatement("sandbox", "ufodata")

// Create index filter
stmt.SetFilter(aerospike.NewRangeFilter("occurred", 20210101, 20211231))

// Execute the query
recordSet, err := client.Query(queryPolicy, stmt)

// Get the results
for records := range recordSet.Results() {
    if records != nil { 
        // Do something
        fmt.Printf("Record: %v \n", records.Record.Bins)
    }
}

recordSet.Close()

// Close the connection to the server
client.Close()
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting nil data. I think this only executes normal query.
select * from test.demo where shopping_cart = "FL" is getting executed I guess. mapvalues part is skipped.
Also I have created a secondary index, and original query is giving me result on aql console

Comment: oh, I didn't realize the further details around mapvalues... I see you have posted a follow up here: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/mapvalues-query-using-golang/9991. Let's see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Aerospike client for Go. https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go

Comment: I don't think it supports mapvalues

Comment: Seems to support their `BinMap` type? Does that work for you? https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#usage